# Passing parameters to function in CasperJS's evaluate

Tags: javascript, casperjs

How can I pass a parameter to a function within CasperJS's evaluate?

```
    //Should be logged in at this point
    casper.then(function() {
        var counter = 0;
        var cap = 500;

        this.evaluate(function(counter) {
            var children = $('.companies-using-service').children();

            while (counter < children.length) {
                child = children[counter];
                console.log($(child).find('a').attr('data-hint'));
                counter++;
            }
        }, counter);
    });
};

var scrapeClients = function(counter) {
    var children = $('.companies-using-service').children();

    while (counter < children.length) {
        child = children[counter];
        console.log($(child).find('a').attr('data-hint'));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Above, I am able to pass parameters in using an unamed function. However, I wish to pass in the function `scrapeClients` to the evaluate function. In that case, I tried the following `this.evaluate(scrapeClients(counter), counter)`. However, this does not work and the error says that it could not find `$` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are first-class citizen in JavaScript. You can treat them in the same way as variables. You can pass them around. This means that you don't want

```
this.evaluate(scrapeClients(counter), counter)
```

but rather

```
this.evaluate(scrapeClients, counter)
```

In the first case, you're actually calling the function directly. Since the function uses some page properties that are only available inside of `casper.evaluate`, this will throw an error and stop the script.